# How can I get Chrome to use my correct location on a Windows 11 PC?

Tags: google-chrome, location

I cannot get Chrome on my Windows 11 PC to use my correct location. I read many different sites and have done the following:

1. Reset Chrome cache and settings
2. Deleted AppData\Local\Google and used Chrome with no sign in
3. FireFox and Edge show my correct location at location sites
4. Going to maps.google.com in either FireFox or Edge does locate me correctly
5. Used Microsoft Maps and set my location at my street address
6. Created a new user on same machine and used Chrome from scratch with no difference
7. Used Chrome on another computer with ethernet on same local network and does ok
8. Uninstalled Chrome and deleted AppData\Local\Google in all user profiles. Downloaded and Reinstalled Chrome. Now the location is different and all the above still apply, except Chrome shows me in Nashville, TN instead of Detroit, MI for all users on the same machine, which is not correct.

One week ago I changed the T-Mobile home internet gateway due to issues. Yesterday was the first time I needed to do anything requiring location in Chrome for my user on this machine. It didn't show location correctly. If it was the router or location info from the internet, it seems that would happen to the other machine on the same local network, but that machine has no location issues and is unaffected.

Comment: In view of the ISP changes, see if a TCP/IP Reset fixes this issue.  .....  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: Thanks. No difference.

Comment: Try this:   Uninstall Chrome.  Do a Windows 11 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link.  Start with Keep Everything.  When all done, install Chrome and test.

Comment: I did uninstall Chrome per my remarks above. But I can't wipe out everything I have and reinstall Windows. Not willing to do that. Hoping someone will give a targeted solution.

Comment: Repair Install does NOT wipe everything out. Keep Everything does just that.

Comment: I have another Windows OS on a different partition on this machine. I use it to back up the main partition. It has the same Chrome issue. So I'm not going to repair the main Windows OS.

Comment: I think that just means the error on one  of the partitions was backed up to the other partition so both systems have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome seems to not use the windows location API by default now. Here are the steps to force it to:

- enter `chrome://flags` into Chrome's address bar.
- search for 'WinRT Geolocation Implementation'
- Change that setting to 'enabled'
- Restart Chrome and do something in it that needs to get your location

In windows settings > Privacy and Security > Location, you should now see Chrome listed in the 'Let desktop apps access your location' section. Of course that needs to be enabled for this to work.